# user building a filter ('selection') from a drop down list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wrote this code:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">  
<!--  
function PassClient(){  
    var InputValueClient = document.getElementById('ValueClient').value;
    if(document.getElementById('storevaluesClient').value == false ) {document.getElementById('storevaluesClient').innerHTML = InputValueClient;}

    else {
        document.getElementById('storevaluesClient').innerHTML += ", "+InputValueClient;    
        } 
}     
//-->  
</script>


<select multiple="multiple" style="height:80px" name="ValueClient" id="ValueClient" onclick="PassClient()">
    <option value="Mike">Mike</option>
    <option value="Bell">Bell</option>
    <option value="Natal">Natal</option>
    <option value="Charlie">Charlie</option>
    <option value="Nour">Nour</option>
</select>

<textarea rows="6" cols="80" id="storevaluesClient" name="storevaluesClient"  style="font-family:Zurich Ex BT; color:#98AFC7"></textarea>
```

it basically when you click on the list the element move to the Textarea, it a SORT of a  user building a selection, the list goes to more than 100 name.

The problem is that when you click back and forth from client box to client selection to remove or update a selected client name, the form doesn’t allow you select any more clients once you click the box and make changes to it.

Do you guys have suggestion of any solution or an alternative method to do similar thing.

any thoughts our help will be heighly appreciated!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change both `.innerHTML` to `.value`. `document.getElementById('storevaluesClient').value`

Comment: it works prefect!! Thank you so much!! do you have any idea why innerHTML is not working? Your edit to the question and your great answer are highly appreciated! Thanks again!

Comment: @mongotop .innerHTML is generally for container elements such as div and span. .value is for form elements. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">  
<!--
var InputValueClient;
var ValueClient;
function PassClient(){  
    InputValueClient = document.getElementById('ValueClient');
    ValueClient = document.getElementById('storevaluesClient');

    if(ValueClient.value == false ) {
        ValueClient.value = InputValueClient.value;
    }else {
        ValueClient.value += ", "+InputValueClient.value;    
    } 
}
//-->
</script>

<select multiple="multiple" style="height:80px" name="ValueClient" id="ValueClient" onclick="PassClient()">
    <option value="Mike">Mike</option>
    <option value="Bell">Bell</option>
    <option value="Natal">Natal</option>
    <option value="Charlie">Charlie</option>
    <option value="Nour">Nour</option>
</select>

<textarea rows="6" cols="80" id="storevaluesClient" name="storevaluesClient" style="font-family:Zurich Ex BT; color:#98AFC7"></textarea>
```